# Python: how to randomly sample from nonstandard Cauchy distribution, hence with different parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, distribution

I was looking here: [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_cauchy.html)

And I can see you can use the command `np.random.standard_cauchy()` specifying an array, to sample from a standard Cauchy.

I need to sample from a Cauchy which might have `x_0 != 0` and `gamma != 1`, i.e. might not be located at the origin, nor have scale equal to 1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have scipy, you can use [`scipy.stats.cauchy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cauchy.html), which takes a location (x0) and a scale (gamma) parameter. It exposes the `rvs` method to draw random samples:

```
x = stats.cauchy.rvs(loc=100, scale=2.5, size=1000)  # draw 1000 samples
```

Answer (score 6):

You may avoid the dependency on SciPy, since the Cauchy distribution is part of the [location-scale family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family). That means, if you draw a sample `x` from `Cauchy(0, 1)`, just shift it by `x_0` and multiply with `gamma` and `x' = x_0 + gamma * x` will be distributed according to `Cauchy(x_0, gamma)`.